# mediasoup-client TypeError: Cannot read property '_createTransport' of null at createRecvTransport

Tags: mediasoup

I've got an error in mediasoup-client while executing "device.createRecvTransport" in the Redux SAGA (I know this is not the best practice, but no choice).

"device.createRecvTransport" is actually an abstraction which holds a webRTC RTCPeerConnection instance. When I call it, it throws this error.

`TypeError: Cannot read property '_createTransport' of null at createRecvTransport`

the code:

```
function* createRecvTransport(device: Device) {
  const {
    id,
    iceParameters,
    iceCandidates,
    dtlsParameters,
    sctpParameters
  } = yield sendRequest({
    action: 'createWebRtcTransport',
    data: {
      forceTcp: false,
      producing: false,
      consuming: true
    }
  });

  const recvTransport: Transport = yield call(device.createRecvTransport, {
    id,
    iceParameters,
    iceCandidates,
    dtlsParameters,
    sctpParameters,
    iceServers: []
  });
}
```

the Device is declared with function

```
function* initDevice() {
  const handlerName = detectDevice();
  const device = new Device({
    handlerName
  });

  const routerRtpCapabilities = yield sendRequest({
    action: 'getRouterRtpCapabilities'
  });

  device.load({ routerRtpCapabilities });
}
```

"device.createSendTransport" method also works, the only issue is with creating Receive Transport. The method "router.createWebRtcTransport" get executed in the mediasoup router and it returns data before executing "createRecvTransport" in client side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems the problem is with the "yield call" expression.
As the "device.createRecvTransport" isn't an async (handled with promise) function, it shouldn't be executed using "yield call".

When I removed "yield call", it fixed.